# Three mutually perpendicular chords in a sphere with radius R

Tags: spheres, solid-geometry

In a sphere, with radius R, there are three mutually perpendicular chords. They intersect at a point P (not the center). Point P divides the three chords into segments: a, b, c, d, e, f.

**Is it true that: a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 = 6R^2**

Comment: Hi! I solved the other problem before I realized you deleted it. You can find the solution here https://imgur.com/uFV6LV0

Comment: Hello! Thank you very much @Raffaele for your simple and clear explanation! You did it with GeoGebra?

Comment: Just the drawing and the $LaTeX$

Comment: @Steve Phoenix You should undelete the other problem in order Raffaele can give his solution. I have myself my own solution too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not true. More precisely,
$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 = 2\,(3\,R^2-r^2),$$ where $r$ is the distance of $P$ from the center of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you for you answer NoNames